# Submitting post data via jquery .ajax to another domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

For the life of me I cannot get this to work. I get the alert back when the test.php file is on the same server as this application, but if I point it to another domain, it does not work at all. The function is:

```
        $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.mycrossdomain.co.uk/test.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    }
    });
```

Does anybody have any useful printers?

Answer (score 8):

That is [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) at work.

You can't [post](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) (that is, the HTTP POST request method with key value pairs as body) to a different domain, protocol and/or port via XHR.

You could play around with [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) but know it is not supported in < IE8.

You can, however, submit a form to a different URL.

Comment: Melissa, that was rude. No, you can't. It's a browser security feature and you will not be able to do so with any normal browser.

Comment: @melissa jones I just flagged your comment

Comment: While I agree the comment is a little overboard, to go so far as saying that the only thing you can do is submit a form to a different URL is far from the truth.  If she owns the external url, or if the external domain offers support for JSONP requests, than this is entirely possible to implement.  While it won't be a true XHR request, it will still function with jQuery as expected.  The question wasn't "is a cross-domain XHR request possible", the question was "Submitting post data via jquery .ajax to another domain", which is entirely possible given the right conditions are met.

Comment: @Brad See the "via XHR" there?

Comment: Yes I see where *YOU* specified XHR, but once again, the original post didn't specify "XHR" - the original post specified "via jquery .ajax to another domain" - the jquery ajax wrapper natively supports JSONP / crossdomain requests.  Have you ever even used jQuery, or are you simply making assumptions that a jQuery .ajax call will always use XHR?

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make this work is to create a "proxy" page on your server where the JS lives that will relay the data you send via the JSON request to the third party server and will return the results directly to your script.  The problem here (as is pointed out in the comments below) is that while you can get a JSONP request to work to another domain, you cannot send the data via a *POST* request; this is because all a "JSONP request" does is insert a script tag into your DOM, so the only option you have is passing params via GET via the script src url.

Comment: So where is the *POST*ing in your answer? Do you regularly echo unescaped user input?

Comment: What are you talking about?  Have you ever used jQuery, or are you simply just trying to argue for arguments sake because you don't feel like acknowledging that this is in fact possible?  The OP makes no mention whatsoever of POST being a requirement or that the request *must* be an XHR request for that matter.

Comment: The title of the question is *Submitting **post data** via jquery*?

Comment: +1 for the local proxy suggestion, pretty sure it's the only way forward

Comment: Alex - you're right, I wasn't thinking about that part about POST requests not being possible with JSONP.  Edited my answer to reflect the only way that this can be done with POST